# Trying to use the new SwiftData framework with a predicate, but I am receiving an "Unsupported Predicate" error

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I am trying to run a function in my SwiftUI project utilizing SwiftData.

The function in question:

```
private func forgetVerse() {
        
    withAnimation {
        let predicate = #Predicate<Memorize> {
            $0.chapter == verse.chapter &&
            $0.verse == verse.verse
        }
        let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Memorize>(predicate: predicate)
            
        do {
            let objects = try context.fetch(descriptor)
            context.delete(objects.first!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this function, I get the following error:

> SwiftDataError(_error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError._Error.unsupportedPredicate)

I am not familiar with this error, and I am not able to find any information on it. Is there something wrong with my approach to using `#Predicate`?

For reference, here is my model:

```
@Model
final class Memorize {
    var chapter: Int
    var verse: Int
    
    init(chapter: Int, verse: Int) {
        self.chapter = chapter
        self.verse = verse
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a dynamic predicate similar to yours and got it to work when used together with a `@State` property in my view

Comment: I am getting the same when using Date. The model with Date do not compare in #Predicate. Throwing unsupported predicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/predicate

"A predicate can’t contain any nested declarations, use any flow control such as for loops, or modify variables from its enclosing scope. However, it can refer to **constants that are in scope.**"

I suppose your variable `verse` is not a constant.

Comment: Could you clarify which variables you are referring to?

Comment: verse is the variable

Comment: I tried changing `verse` from a `var` to a `let`. It did not change anything. Oh well, it was a good guess...

Comment: That probably wouldn't help. Try to use a value instead of an object.

Comment: This suggestion worked. Thank you sir!